# Min() and Max() based on partition in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, min

I want to use  min & max function but on certain criteria.

```
Create Table #Test (Id Int Identity(1,1), Category Varchar(100), DateTimeStamp DateTime)



    Insert into #Test (Category,DateTimeStamp) values ('c1','2019-08-13 01:00:13.503')
        Insert into #Test (Category,DateTimeStamp) values ('c1','2019-08-13 02:00:13.503')
        Insert into #Test (Category,DateTimeStamp) values ('c1','2019-08-13 03:00:13.503')
        Insert into #Test (Category,DateTimeStamp) values ('c1','2019-08-13 04:00:13.503')
        Insert into #Test (Category,DateTimeStamp) values ('c1','2019-08-13 05:00:13.503')
        Insert into #Test (Category,DateTimeStamp) values ('c2','2019-08-13 06:00:13.503')
        Insert into #Test (Category,DateTimeStamp) values ('c2','2019-08-13 07:00:13.503')
        Insert into #Test (Category,DateTimeStamp) values ('c2','2019-08-13 08:00:13.503')
        Insert into #Test (Category,DateTimeStamp) values ('c2','2019-08-13 09:00:13.503')
        Insert into #Test (Category,DateTimeStamp) values ('c2','2019-08-13 10:00:13.503')  
        Insert into #Test (Category,DateTimeStamp) values ('c1','2019-08-13 11:00:13.503')
```

Current Query With Output

```
select category, min(DateTimeStamp) as minn , max(DateTimeStamp) as maxx from #Test
group by category
```

**Current Output**

[image: Current Output]

**Expected Output**

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: I have also shared sample sql data script and current sql query.

Comment: That's really great!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try below - it's a gap & island problem

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=ec9e023e8a4d6e298f9063683be036b7)**

```
select category, min(datetimestamp),max(datetimestamp)
from
(
select *,row_number() over(order by datetimestamp) -
row_number() over(partition by category order by datetimestamp) as rn2
from #Test
)A group by category,rn2 order by 2
```

OUTPUT:

```
category       minval               maxval
c1             13/08/2019 01:00:13  13/08/2019 05:00:13
c2             13/08/2019 06:00:13  13/08/2019 10:00:13
c1             13/08/2019 11:00:13  13/08/2019 11:00:13
```

Answer (score 1):

For postgres:

```sql
SELECT category, min(DateTimeStamp) as minn , max(DateTimeStamp) as maxx 
FROM (Select *,
      SUM(CASE WHEN Category <> PrevCategory THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  OVER (ORDER BY 
      ID,Category,DateTimeStamp) As partition
      From (Select * ,LAG (Category, 1) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS PrevCategory From Test)  As 
           help) As helper 
GROUP BY category,partition;
```